# 80s/90s sci fi book/story: bored protagonist is mind-wiped and sent by interstellar government on an unhabited planet to form a new society

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for an old sci fi book which I read over a decade ago. I don’t know the publication date but I guess somewhere in the 1980s or 90s. It was quite a short story.

It was about a person in the far future which was unhappy in it, because in that future the interstellar "government" or whatever had absolute control and technology gave the people everything they needed and wanted for free. Which led to people getting bored and numb.

Then the main character got an invitation from the government. They know "everything" and knew he was unhappy. They said they just discovered a new unhabited planet and wanted to try something with people like him.
To get them something exiting in their lives again
The proposal was to wipe the memory of the main character and a few dozen other people clean and then set them free on the new planet without any memories.
They became like cavemen on that planet.

They formed some kind of society and tried to get by somehow. Some people died to wild animals or because of illness or childbirths and at some point towards the end the main character got his memory of the past back because of a head injury or something.

That's when he realized that all this was some kind of entertainment show for the bored people on the "civilized" planets and they were watched by satellites and stuff.